# To show videos in some CHM viewer

Tags: mediaplayer

CHM is an extension for the Compiled HTML file format. 
There are many viewers with different quality. 
xCHM has been my choice because of robust search, [here](http://xchm.sourceforge.net/) their homepage. 
I however just noticed that some files are incorporated with videos but my viewer cannot show them.

**How can you view CHM videos in OSX?**
Any good option for this.

Answer (score 2):

Since I cannot comment your question for lack of rep, I'd suggest you try [iChm 1.4.3](http://ichm.googlecode.com/files/iChm.1.4.3.zip) or [1.5.0](http://www.markdouma.com/developer/iChm.zip). Latter was recently released, so if video doesn't work (a feature I didn't know about in CHM, by the way), I'd suggest you open an issue in the [tracker](https://github.com/NSGod/ichm).

Comment: I voted you up so you can comment soon. I think your proposals are completely valid as an answer. I would like to get any reviews about those viewers. The thing is now that I cannot remember which file was embedded with video so I cannot test it.

Comment: I only use 1.4.3 with [QuickChm 1.1](http://sourceforge.net/projects/quickchm/files/quickchm/quickchm1.1/), but lack a Spotlight importer. 1.5 added an importer but seems to break QL. I'll head to the tracker for both issues.

Comment: Please, add tickets IDs here too so we can follow them.

Comment: I opened a thread about generating .chm document with LaTeX here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/303549/13173 so we can get test inputs.

Comment: @Masi, you can check [#1](https://github.com/NSGod/ichm/issues/1) and [#2](https://github.com/NSGod/ichm/issues/2).